# Block network with Network Link Conditioner?

Tags: macos, xcode-simulator

Any one know how to block all network traffic with the `Network Link Conditioner` on Mountain Lion? Here's the custom offline profile I made that's not working. I'm trying to block the network for the iPhone Simulator. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want the answer how to block traffic rather than using the tool you have at hand, I'll suggest you use [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).

It is a firewall that works on interrupting the flow of data out from apps to the internet.

Perhaps someone will know how to bend the Network Link Conditioner to work as a firewall for the one app, but I'd start with one of the tools for that job if no one has a good recipe for the latter.